# How to set default url or startup page in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

When i'm creating routing in asp.net core 2.2 with companyname and controller. My application shows 404 error for the following code when I hit F5.

`app.UseMvc(route =>
            {
                route.MapRoute("Default", "MyCompany/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });`

If I enter the full path it is working.

If I remove **MyCompany** before the controller, It works fine.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @ArunKuram  You have added this prefix "MyCompany" to your route. So for every route to work you have to specify this prefix in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure your routing to:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "startupRoute",
               template: "/",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }) ;
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "MyCompany/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```